# Combination Problems with big numbers (3, 123) in C

Tags: c

a real newbie to c here.. been learning it for 6 weeks now so idk a lot of stuff yet (we just learned nested functions, i'm still making newbie mistakes everywhere..)

I got a hw about combination with 3 parts, and wrote my codes that worked for the first two (like (3,10))
but I found that the third part was (3, 123) and of course my codes couldn't handle it without overflowing

here's the code that I wrote:

```
#include<stdio.h>

long long int factorial(int x)   
{   int y; 
    long long int z=1;
    for (y=1; y<=x; y++)
    {z*=y;}
    return z;
}

long long int combination(int b, int c) 
{long long int a, d, e; 
a= factorial(c);
d= factorial(c-b) * factorial(b);
e= a/d;
return e;
}

int main()
{   int draws, total;
    scanf("%d %d", &draws, &total);
    printf("%lld", combination(draws, total));
    return 0;
}
```

works right upto long long int ofc but nothing like 123!
I spent like 2-3 hours digging around the internet and found some stuff like itoa (no idea what that is.. never heard of it), array, string etc but that just helps store the value and doesn't help with the actual calculation.. and something called GMP? tried putting #include< gmp.h> and it said that it cant find it. if it gives that error then im pretty sure i cant use it for my hw. tbh idk y our teacher gave us this considering he didnt tell us how to solve these kinds of huge number overflow issue.. lol. thank you so much for the help.

Comment: Maybe the goal of your professor with the number 123 is to see how you can handle error case in your code. If you really want to handle that case you'll need to implement the BigInt type in c.

Comment: The term "nested functions" is wrong here. What do you mean here??

Comment: @Jabberwocky yeah I see that now. i meant main-->combination-->factorial. idk how that's called, and just did a search to see that it's not nested lol. thanks for pointing that out

Comment: The trick is to calculate the "falling factorial" x to the n falling, x*(x-1)*...*(x+n-1), and divide that by n!. In this case, x=123 and n=3, so 123*122*121 / (3*2*1) = 302621.

Comment: @menett_a yeah that's the goal. unfortunately that's where i got stuck lol. aint looking for direct answers, but a push towards the right direction would be good. is BigInt type something that is standard in C or does it require additional download? (cause from what i saw something like GMP needed download?) i doubt i can download additional stuff for my hw. if "download" isnt how C works, you can see how clueless I am lol

Comment: @IanAbbott oh wow that I did not think of. thank you so much! :)

Comment: @CurryFlurry you can [edit] your question. Anyway, calling a function from another function is nothing special.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parameters are backwards for the normal use of combination function. For combinations of n things taken k at a time, the syntax is comb(n,k). To reduce the size of the numbers involved:

```
c = max(k, n-k)
d = n-c
comb(n,k) = (n)(n-1)(n-2)...(n+1-c)/(d!)
```

examples:

```
comb(6,2)
c = max(2, 6-2) = 4
d = 6-4 = 2
comb(6,2) = (6·5)/(2·1) = 15

comb(123,3)
c = max(3, 123-3) = 120
d = n-c = 3
comb(123,3) = (123·122·121)/(3·2·1) = 302621
```

Comment: Nice use of symmetry to help avoid overflow!

Comment: This works well if `binomial(n,k)` is small. For large values use [Borwein's trick](http://www.cecm.sfu.ca/personal/pborwein/PAPERS/P29.pdf) and subtract the exponents. The resulting primorials can be computed with binary splitting if large enough (Schönhage et al. "Fast Algorithms, A Multitape Turing Machine Implementation", BI Wissenschaftsverlag, 1994 Not found online but Arnold Schönhage sells it directly for 16 Euro (about $18) [from home](https://pages.iai.uni-bonn.de/schoenhage_arnold/tp/TPbook.html) if you want to support the authors directly or for 15.30 Euro from Amazon)

Comment: @deamentiaemundi - modern [big integer libraries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_arbitrary-precision_arithmetic_software) would probably be faster.